# Dataset of English Poetry

Tags: data-request, language, english

Is there a dataset containing a group of poems in English? I couldn't find any resource online. I could web scrape poetry sites, but I want to avoid copyright issues and even a dataset of older poems would do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure public domain poetry, you can use [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org). In particular, they have a "[Bookshelf](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Poetry_(Bookshelf))" specific to poetry. With some exceptions, Project Gutenberg is mostly English.

You can download all of Project Gutenberg, with their [Harvest](https://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest) site. [See here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/12312) for more details - downloading with `wget`.

Probably more useful is to use a wrapper library like [Python's Gutenberg](https://github.com/c-w/Gutenberg). In this case, you would feed a list of e-book IDs (e.g. 12924) from the Bookshelf link to a python code, then download all the TXT data.

```
from gutenberg.acquire import load_etext
from gutenberg.cleanup import strip_headers

id_list = [12924, 16786] # better is to read a parameter file
for id_nr in id_list: # loop over list
    text = strip_headers(load_etext(id_nr)).strip()
    # actually do something with `text`
```

Other languages have wrappers, too.

Comment: Is Project Gutenberg part of the US open data initiative? I didn't know that. So the U.S.government has data on "cultural" matters?